# Организация видеообщения в Android

Tags: android, камера

Вопрос чисто образовательного характера. Я новичок и вот задался таким вопросом.
Допустим, извесно 2 ip-шника, как между этими адресами организовать видеосвязь?

В гугле как-то маловато инфы или просто неверно ищу. 
Может, у кого завалялись туториалы, или видос какой-нибудь, или ссылочки, буду благодарен за любую инфу. Спасибо большое.

Comment: Плохо искали.    
https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=android+video+streaming+from+device+example    
https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=android+video+streaming+from+device+example    
заняло 2 минуты

Comment: спасибо, конечно, но все равно ничего не понятно. Мне бы почитать, что-нибудь, желательно на русском, о том, как именно организовать сетевое взаимодействие двух девайсов. Вот с текстом все в принципе просто. А что делать с потоком видео и аудио, не понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Вот первое, что мне попало:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401340/live-stream-video-from-one-android-phone-to-another-over-wifi

Написал всего-то в гугле: **android camera stream api example**.

Comment: спасибо, конечно, но все равно ничего не понятно. Мне бы почитать, что-нибудь, желательно на русском, о том, как именно организовать сетевое взаимодействие двух девайсов. Вот с текстом все в принципе просто. А что делать с потоком видео и аудио, не понятно.